# NoClassDefFound in gradle scripts while working with google play services

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play-services, noclassdeffounderror

I am facing very strange problem.
I am using google play services library as a dependency for my project.
When I run from eclipse everything is fine, but when I build my apk with gradle script, I get the following exception

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics

Strange part is I see this class in .aar of my library project but when i decompile my final apk, this class is not present. I am not using proguard, so I am NOT sure why this class is not being copied from aar file to final apk.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem.. The reason why some classes from service play jar was not being copied in apk was because jar was built on Java 7 and dx tool was not able to process it. I changed the build tool version in gradle script from 18.0.1(dx can only process java 6) to 19.0.3( dx tool can process Java 7). Hopefully this will help other people.